# How to test deep cloning with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, clone, deep-copy

I have implemented `__clone` on a class to clone the child objects (i.e. Deep cloning.)

I want to write tests to ensure this process is correctly implemented.

When I mock the a child object and try to set an expectation on the '__clone', PHPUnit errors because the method is not defined.  This is an example how I'm trying to write the assertion.

```
<?php

public function testClone()
{
    $mockChildObject = $this->createMock(ChildObject::class);
    $mockChildObjectClone = $this->createMock(ChildObject::class);
    $mockChildObject->expects($this->once())->method('__clone')->willReturn($this->createMock($mockChildObjectClone));

    $object = new MyObject();
    $object->addChild($mockChildObject);

    $objectClone = clone $object;

    $this->assertSame($mockChildObjectClone, $objectClone->getChild());
}
```

The resulting error reads:

> Trying to configure method "__clone" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

The `__clone` method is not implemented on the child objects because the default cloning is sufficient.

I have also tried using `$this->getMockBuilder()` with various combinations of `disableOriginalClone()`/`enableOriginalClone()` and `enableArgumentCloning()`/`diableArgumentCloning()`.

The only way I can think of test cloning is to write an another class that extends the child object and implements `__clone()`.  But this seems excessive and I'm sure there must be a more practical solution.

Comment: Can you call a template method from within clone, and mock *that* method instead? so for example within your `__clone`, call `return $this->myActualCloneMethod()` and mock the `myActualCloneMethod` method. Without testing I'm assuming it will always be called.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed, that calling `disableOriginalClone` method on `MockBuilder` will be equivalent to the following code (if `__clone` method was not in the prohibited methods to mock list and did not produce a warning):

```
$yourMock->expects($this->once())->method('__clone')->with()->willReutrnSelf();
```

That is why for mocking clone method U can simply use `disableOriginalClone` method.

Answer (score 0):

Late for party, but you could utilize `assertNotSame`:

```
<?php

public function testClone()
{
    $sut = new MyObject();
    $sut->addChild(
        $originalMock = $this->createMock(ChildObject::class)
    );
    
    $sutClone = clone $sut;

    $this->assertNotSame($originalMock, $sutClone->getChild());
}
```

According to [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertsame), `assertSame`

> Reports an error identified by $message if the two variables $expected and $actual do not reference the same object.

which is exactly what you need to test: that the child of cloned SUT is not the original child.